# Serviceworker registration - weird issue

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

On my PWA dev machine, when I open it using localhost/127.0.0.1 it works fine, DOM has navigator.serviceWorker

However when I am trying using public url (using grok)- DOM is not having serviceWorker in navigator

Same machine, same browser but strange issue.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tested your HTTPS url with the chrome lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it willl usually give helpful hints.

Comment: @Mathias - Thanks for help, https has worked!

Answer (score 1):

Once you get past dev testing, your PWA URL needs to be HTTPS
If there are still issues, use the Chrome Lighthouse tool to give you hints on what still needs to be corrected